# How can I import data from PostgreSQL into Salesforce?

Tags: postgresql, salesforce

I see a lot of information on how to go from Salesforce to PostgreSQL but not a lot going the other way.  Can somebody suggest a service that might do this?  Preferably something with a scheduler, as I'd like to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

Export your database into a CSV and import it using the [SalesForce Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=5) tool.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've been more specific.  I need to do it directly from PostgreSQL.  Also, automating that would be a pain.